# Generalization of prime and irreducible elements to arbitary magmas

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, magma

Has anyone ever given a general definition of prime and irreducible elements in arbitrary magmas, that is to say, sets with a single binary operation with no restrictions? I know Walter Noll has given a definition for monoids in his website, specifically here: http://www.math.cmu.edu/~wn0g/monoids.pdf. Is there some webpage where there is such a definition?

Comment: Could you give the link to the paper you mention?

Comment: The linked article looks interesting...